# Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'Type'

Tags: flutter, dart, white-labelling

I'm white-labelling an app so, in root app I have a config.dart with all my brand variables:

```dart
final WIDGET_ONE_CONTROLLER = null;

final WIDGET_TWO_CONTROLLER = null;

...
```

And I use this variable in my widgets:

```dart
final widgetOneController = WIDGET_ONE_CONTROLLER(myParameter);
```

But it throws this error:

> Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'Type'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'call'.
> WIDGET_ONE_CONTROLLER(myParameter);

In my brand app I define the controllers in this way:

```dart
import 'package:config/controllers/widget_one_controller.dart';
import 'package:config/controllers/widget_two_controller.dart';

final WIDGET_ONE_CONTROLLER = WidgetOneController;

final WIDGET_TWO_CONTROLLER = WidgetTwoController;
```

How have I to pass the widgets in my brand file to be able to use it and create objects (or pass the object directly) to root app?

Comment: What do you want to pass in your parameter? Since you are defining a final null object, not a method?

Comment: I wanna pass the class I have in brand app to use its objects within root app code. The null is to initialise only

Comment: You cannot use the (myParameter) on a type (your type is the final null variable), you can only use it on classes. Consider directly importing the controllers and initializing them with: new WidgetOneController();

Comment: I can't import because the classes are in the child app.. is another project

Comment: I saw about defining a 'call' method.. but don't found this specific example.. Do you have experience with it?